# Pass Headers to Proxy Server from the Frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http-headers

I have a frontend that makes a call to my proxy server, which then makes a call to an Application API. When I set the header (api key) in my backend, everything works fine, but when i try to pass the key from the frontend, I get `GET http://localhost:3000/names net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

How can I pass the headers to the proxy server from the frontend and successfully make a call?

`frontend`

```
const requestnames = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
    headers: {
        "x-id-key":
          "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      },
  });

  export const getNames = () => {
    return requestnames.get("/names", {});
  };
```

`backend`

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello!"));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`http://localhost:${port}`));

app.use(cors());

const apicall = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://bk/api/v1",
});

const getAllNames = (req, res) => {
    apicall.get("/names").then((data) => res.send(data.data));
};

app.get("/names", getAllNames);
```

Comment: Read the request headers in your backend code, and then add them to the axios request you are making there - where is the problem with that?

Comment: @CBroe how can i read the request. I tried using `req.headers`, but got a `req not defined` error. So my problem is how to implement it.